# imprimir valores não repetidos

Tags: c

boa noite, tô desenvolvendo uma questão, já está quase completa, to conseguindo excluir valores repetidos sequencialmente, por exemplo: 1 1 2 3 4 5 1, tal qual exclui 1 e 1 e deixa somente 2 3 4 5 1, no entanto, se eu digito 1 2 3 4 1, ele imprime essa sequência, sem remover os repetidos, o que devo alterar no meu código para resolver isso? se alguém poder ajudar, agradeço.
segue anexo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int vet[10];
    int pos[10];
    int semdup[10];
    int qtd=0; int qtd1=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
        if (vet[i]>0) {
            pos[qtd++] = vet[i];
        } else {
            printf("Negativo.\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", vet[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < qtd; ++i) {     
        printf("%d ", pos[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < qtd; ++i) {     
            if (pos[i] == pos[i+1]) {
                pos[i] = pos[i+1];
                        
            } else {
                semdup[qtd1++] = pos[i];
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < qtd1; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", semdup[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digamos que vc tem um array com elementos repitidos e fora de ordem `1, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 1` e deseja imprimir na tela somento os valores que não são repitidos `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Primeiro, devemos organizar o array em ordem crescente, ou seja,`1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5`. Pra isso percorremos o array, item por item, e testamos se o item atual é maior que o proximo item. Se verdadeiro, movemos de lugar o item de maior valor dentro do array.

Segundo, devemos percorrer o array testando se o item atual é diferente do proximo item, se for devemos imprimir o valor na tela, resultando em `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 1};
    int size = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
    
    /*ORGANIZA ARRAY */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j)
        {
 
            if (array[i] > array[j]) 
            {
                int a = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = a;
            }
 
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        if(j <= size)
        {
            if(array[i] != array[j])
            {
                printf("%d\n",array[i]);  
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: agradeço muito pela sua ajuda, nao havia pensado em ordenar, ainda sou meio ruim nessa área, deu certo ordenando, valeu.